# The relation of the local principal representations of $U(2)$ and $GL(2)$

Tags: automorphic-forms, unitary-representations, induced-representations, admissible-representation

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of number fields and $v$ is a non-archimedean place of $F$.

Let $G=U(2)(F_v)$ be the $F_v$-points of the 2-dimension unitary group associated to $E_v/F_v$ and $B$, $T$ be the Borel subgroup and a torus of $G$ respectively.

Note that $B=T\simeq E_v^{\times}$.

Let $\chi$ be an unramified unitary character of $E_v^{\times}$ and $\pi=\text{Ind}_B^G \chi$ be the unramified induced irreducible representation of $G$ induced from $\chi$. (Here the induction is normalized by $\delta_B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\delta_B$ is the modulus character of $B$.)

If $v$ is split, then $E_v=F_v \times F_v$ and so $U(2)(F_v)\simeq GL(2)(F_v)$.

In this case, if we write $\chi=(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ where $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are an unramified unitary characters of $F^{\times}$, then I suppose we can see $\pi$ as $B(\chi_1,\chi_2^{-1})$, the unramified principal representation of $GL(2)(F_v)$.

My reasoning for this is as follows;

If $f\in \pi=\text{Ind}_B^G \chi$, then $f$ satisfies $f(\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \\  & \bar{\alpha}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}x)=\chi(det(\alpha))|det(\alpha)|^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)$ where $\alpha\in GL_1(E_v)=E_v^{\times}$ and $g \in G$.

Let the isomorphism between $U(2)(F_v)$ and $GL_2(F_v)$ be the projection to the first component. Then the diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix} (a,b) & \\  &(b^{-1},a^{-1})\end{pmatrix} \in U(2)(F_v)$ is identified with $\begin{pmatrix} a & \\  & b^{-1}\end{pmatrix} \in GL_2(F_v)$. Therefore if we think $\pi$ as a representation of $GL_2(F_v)$, then for $f\in \text{Ind}_B^G \chi$ should satisfy $f(\begin{pmatrix} a & \\  & b^{-1}\end{pmatrix}x)=\chi_1(a)\chi_2(b)|ab|^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)$.
(here we write $\alpha=(a,b)$.)

If we make a substitution $b$ to $b^{-1}$, this condition becomes

$f(\begin{pmatrix} a & \\  & b\end{pmatrix}x)=\chi_1(a)\chi_2^{-1}(b)|\frac{a}{b}|^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)$ and thus $f$ should be in $B(\chi_1,\chi_2^{-1})$.

My reasoning is right?

If there is something wrong, I would truly appreciate you letting me know of it.

Thanks for reading this post.

Comment: What is the question?